# Check if currently logged in user has persistent authcookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, persistence, forms-authentication

I need to edit userdata in an a FormsAuthentication AuthCookie of the currently logged in user. I don't see how to find out if the current user has chosen a persistent cookie ("Remember Me").

```
//user is already logged in...

HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(username, ispersistant); //how to I determine 'ispersistant'?

FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

FormsAuthenticationTicket newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate, ticket.Expiration, ticket.IsPersistent, NEWuserdata);

authCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);

HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(authCookie);
```

Anybody got any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie` method only creates a new cookie. It does not get you the earlier made cookie.

On your login page you probably have something like this:

```
FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie (userID, chkPersistCookie.Checked)
```

And to know when the user is authenticated you can do

```
this.Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

I actually don't know for sure if you can deduce the fact that the user has a persistent auth cookie. One thing is checking the cookie for a expiry date.

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939533/cookie-confusion-with-formsauthentication-setauthcookie-method) there is a example for reading the authentication cookie.

Answer (score 7):

This should retrieve the existing forms auth cookie, examine the ticket, and tell if it's persistent.

```
        var FormsAuthCookie = Response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        var ExistingTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(FormsAuthCookie.Value);
        bool IsPersistent = ExistingTicket.IsPersistent;
```

Comment: I get `FormsAuthCookie.Value` with empty value

Comment: Depending on your scenario you might want to get the cookie from the **Request** and not the **Response**:
`HttpCookie formsAuthCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];`

Answer (score 2):

I ended up storing "ispersistant" in the userdata property of the authcookie on login.