# How to set remember me in login page without using membeship in MVC 2.0

Tags: model-view-controller

I am using MVC 2.0. I want to set a cooking to login the user for 1 year if user click on the check for login. I dont want user any authentication for this. my model is as follow :

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Email Address")]
        [DisplayName("User Name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [DisplayName("Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Remember Me")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
```

and in the view i am using `HTML.CkeckboxFor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Th the post of the controller do this :

```
if (model.RememberMe == true)
                    {

                        Response.Cookies["Login"]["UserName"] = model.UserName;
                        Response.Cookies["Login"]["Password"] = model.Password;
                        Response.Cookies["Login"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
                    }
```

and in the get of controller do this :

HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Login"];

```
if (cookie != null)
            {
                model.UserName = cookie.Values[0];
                model.Password = cookie.Values[1];
}
```

Comment: you should NOT store usernames or/and passwords in cookies like this! Anyone with access to users computer (and a tiny bit of knowledge) will be able to read this. You should take a look at FormsAuthentication. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939533/cookie-confusion-with-formsauthentication-setauthcookie-method

Comment: well its true but if any one is not use FormsAuthentication than is there is any other wat to do ?

Comment: you should at least encrypt values. you should never store passwords in clear text. And you can use some of the FormsAuthentication functions even if you don't use the built in membership provider. Use it to create a FormsAuthenticationTicket.