# How to programmatically set SlidingExpiration to true in mvc Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, forms-authentication

I have an MVC 3 application with an authentification form. When the user checks the checkbox "remember me", the auth cookie must be set to 2 week, and when he doesn't it should be 30 minutes. In both cases the sliding expiration should be turned on. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939533/cookie-confusion-with-formsauthentication-setauthcookie-method) I created following method, that creates custom authentification cookie:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1,  //version
            username,
            DateTime.Now, //issue date
            rememberMe ? DateTime.Now.AddDays(14) : DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), // exprie date
            rememberMe, // is persistent
            null
            );
        var ecnryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, ecnryptedTicket);

        cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration; // to expire cookie together with ticket

        response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

How can I programmatically set sliding expiration after that?

Answer (score 0):

It has been awhile since this was asked, but I ran across this while looking into something else.  If you want to run mixed mode like that you might want to roll your own with something like this:

http://cbertolasio.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/dealing-with-idle-clients-and-expiring-sessions-in-asp-net-mvc/

And when the heartbeat is sent from the plugin extend the ticket if need be.  I get the feeling sliding expiration is a all or nothing option.