# How do I use Forms Authentication to provide stay-logged-in functionality?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I am generating a FormsAuthentication ticket, and storing it in a cookie, which I use with the MVC AuthorizeAttribute to provide authorization. Right now, I've got it so the cookie doesn't expire if I have a "stay signed in" checkbox checked, (I'm just changing the cookie.expires to now + 1 year, for testing purposes, when they've got it checked to stay signed in).

However, even though I set that the cookie is persistent when I create the ticket, the ticket still stops working after the timeout period.

Here's the code where I create the AuthTicket:

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, username, now, now.Add(FormsAuthentication.Timeout), rememberMe, username, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
string encryptedTicket = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
return encryptedTicket;
```

That's the same encryptedTicket that I set as a cookie. Anyone know how I can keep this ticket allowed past the FormsAuthentication timeout? Do I just have to manually mess with the FormsAuthentication Timeout time?

Comment: Can't you use `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`? Do you really need to create your own? Persistent cookie doesn't mean it will last forever, it will last between browser sessions.

Comment: I need to create my own because I can also access this log in from a mobile app, and the app stores the encrypted ticket, and passes that in as part of the request when getting data.

Maybe I've just misunderstood what isPersistent does on the auth ticket. Does it do anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The amount of time the cookie sticks around is not the same as how long the login will stay valid.  Basically, the persistent cookie is a 'should this cookie stick around after the browser closes' and is independent from how long is this login valid.  You can use this to store the username for instance so that a user does not have to re-enter this information when they come back.

If the cookie is valid, but the login has expired within the cookie, you will need to login again.  If you want your login to last longer, you will need to extend the time on your `<forms>` tag in the web.config or you can do this in code, but then you need to recompile if you want to lengthen/shorten the expiration times.

Here are some sites that explain a little further about these concepts:

http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2012/04/05/forms-authentication-remember-me-its-hard-not-too

[Cookie Confusion with FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie() Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939533/cookie-confusion-with-formsauthentication-setauthcookie-method)

Comment: Oh, got it. Basically, I just misunderstood what it did. Thanks. Do you know if the isPersistent does anything to the actual auth ticket, since I'm handling the cookie creation myself?

Comment: Not from my understanding.  The isPersistent only affects the cookie which is the container for the auth ticket.